# Get CPU Temperature Pro grammatically in Java Android 8.0-oreo

Tags: android, cpu-usage, android-8.0-oreo, temperature

I am developing an app of CPU Cooler, in which I want to cool down the temperature of CPU. There are a lot of apps on play store with same functionality which work on real time. I have seen so many links for it but still din't get any useful data.
I had also searched on Ambient Temperature but it returns 0.0 Temperature in my device(Oreo).

All I need some properly working code which can help me out to do this. And I want to know both things that how can I get the current temperature of CPU and  How can I cool it down?

Comment: `links, suggestion or tutorials` questions are off-topic

Comment: have you found any solution?